# Why does psycopg2 raise a postgreSQL error when deploying Django site to Heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku, psycopg2

I am trying to deploy my Django site to heroku and get the following error snippet:

```
2023-05-05T08:42:38.330672+00:00 app[web.1]: from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
2023-05-05T08:42:38.330672+00:00 app[web.1]: SystemError: initialization of _psycopg raised unreported exception
2023-05-05T08:42:38.330718+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-05-05 08:42:38 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2023-05-05T08:42:38.367087+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-05-05 08:42:38 +0000] [2] [WARNING] Worker with pid 8 was terminated due to signal 15
2023-05-05T08:42:38.465035+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-05-05 08:42:38 +0000] [2] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2023-05-05T08:42:38.465071+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-05-05 08:42:38 +0000] [2] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2023-05-05T08:42:38.616316+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2023-05-05T08:42:38.666808+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-05-05T08:42:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2023-05-05T08:42:44.863150+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=a-coders-journey.herokuapp.com request_id=d8e2f6b2-c4f5-461f-8914-a8e84dc13551 fwd="93.204.33.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I have ensured the version of my requirements.txt file has the binary version (psycopg2-binary), and all applicable requirements:

```
 #
# This file is autogenerated by pip-compile with Python 3.8
# by the following command:
#
#    pip-compile --output-file=requirements.txt requirements.in
#
asgiref==3.3.4
    # via
    #   -r requirements.in
    #   django
certifi==2022.12.7
    # via
    #   cloudinary
    #   requests
cffi==1.15.1
    # via cryptography
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
    # via requests
cloudinary==1.25.0
    # via
    #   -r requirements.in
    #   dj3-cloudinary-storage
cryptography==3.4.8
    # via
    #   -r requirements.in
    #   pyjwt
defusedxml==0.7.1
    # via python3-openid
dj-database-url==0.5.0
    # via -r requirements.in
dj3-cloudinary-storage==0.0.5
    # via -r requirements.in
django==3.2.3
    # via
    #   -r requirements.in
    #   django-allauth
    #   django-summernote
django-allauth==0.44.0
    # via -r requirements.in
django-crispy-forms==1.11.2
    # via -r requirements.in
django-summernote==0.8.11.6
    # via -r requirements.in
gunicorn==20.1.0
    # via -r requirements.in
idna==3.4
    # via requests
oauthlib==3.1.1
    # via
    #   -r requirements.in
    #   requests-oauthlib
pillow==9.5.0
    # via -r requirements.in
psycopg2-binary
    # via -r requirements.in
pycparser==2.21
    # via cffi
pyjwt[crypto]==2.1.0
    # via
    #   -r requirements.in
    #   django-allauth
python3-openid==3.2.0
    # via
    #   -r requirements.in
    #   django-allauth
pytz==2021.1
    # via
    #   -r requirements.in
    #   django
requests==2.30.0
    # via
    #   dj3-cloudinary-storage
    #   django-allauth
    #   requests-oauthlib
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
    # via
    #   -r requirements.in
    #   django-allauth
six==1.16.0
    # via cloudinary
sqlparse==0.4.1
    # via
    #   -r requirements.in
    #   django
urllib3==2.0.2
    # via
    #   cloudinary
    #   requests

# The following packages are considered to be unsafe in a requirements file:
# setuptools
```

are installed. I opened a support ticket with heroku and they gave me link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-heroku-postgres#connecting-in-python  and I followed that but no success. My settings.py file, related to the imports and such:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import psycopg2
import dj_database_url
if os.path.isfile('env.py'):
    import env

#,,,other code then:

DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']

conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')

then at the very bottom of the settings.py:

DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600, ssl_require=True)
```

My Python version within Django: Python 3.8.12

Heroku Python version: Python 3.11.3

What am I doing wrong? Why is psycopg2 erroring out, when initializing? Thanks in advance.

I moved from an older version of psycopg2 to the binary version. I tried the Heroku support document walkthrough,

I tried installing a runtime.txt file and forcing the heroku application to use the same version as my Django version, and I have made sure the contents of my env.py file are correctly pointing to the elephantSQL database I am using, both of these variables are also within my Heroku confg vars.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ignore connecting to Python part, it is not relevant to you, for the Django application you need onlty 'Connecting with Django' part.
2. The Django part should be as follows

```
# Define database URL from the environment file
DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']

# Configure default database
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(
        conn_max_age=600,
        conn_health_checks=True,
        ssl_require=True,
    ),
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I tried that, but no success.

Comment: Do you still get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

Iḿ updating what did I do to resolve the same error reported above. I basically uninstalled this package manually

```
$~/venv/bin/pip uninstall psycopg2-binary
```

Then kept the following two packages in requirements.txt and re-deployed. This time deployment cleared the step and moved to next step.

```
psycopg2==2.8.6
psycopg2-binary>=2.8.6
```

Note: mine is not Heroku instance but I´m using DO´s droplet.